# decimal.getcontext().prec is behaving inconsistently in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have been trying to use decimal.getcontext().prec to set the precision for doing numerical calculations. I ran into this issue where the precision I defined using decimal.getcontext().prec would reset to its default value of 28 in the next cell.

I tried to experiment further by assigning the decimal.getcontext() object a name: g_ctx. As you can see in the image below, this change seemed to have worked and now the change I made to the precision value persisted beyond the current cell. But when I tried to see the content of decimal.getcontext() it was still showing the default precision value of 28.

[image]

I also want to add that this issue didn't arise when I ran the same code directly in the python terminal, so I suspect that this problem is related to Jupyter itself.

Incase someone finds it useful, here is some extra info about the Jupyter version I am using:

[image]

DISCLAIMER: This is not a duplicate of the question posted by jim basquiat. I did try to run all cells as the answer there points out, but you can see from the image above that it didn't work.

Comment: as for me it is normal behavier - as for me every cell is like running code in separated terminal and if you don't assign to variable then it is lost - someting like `local variables`. But you should rather ask jupyter's authors for this.

Comment: @furas thanks for the explanation, but is there any reason why the behaviour changes once it is assigned to a variable.

Comment: variable can be keep as global value. without variable it may be treated as local value and it may lost it.